# Python - OpenCV stereoCalibrate() too manu values to unpack

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, stereo-3d

I am using OpenCV for stereo calibration. I have already performed calibration of individual cameras. For the following code snippet:

```
ret, rot, trans, ess, fund = cv2.stereoCalibrate(objectPoints=objpoints,
                                                 imagePoints1=imgpoints1,
                                                 imagePoints2=imgpoints2,
                                                 cameraMatrix1=mtx1,
                                                 distCoeffs1=dist1,
                                                 cameraMatrix2=mtx2,
                                                 distCoeffs2=dist2,
                                                 imageSize=gray1.shape[::-1],
                                                 flags=cv2.CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC)
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "stereoCalibration.py", line 94, in <module>
  flags=cv2.CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC)
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 5)
```

But I already have five variables on the left-hand-side. According to this [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#cv2.stereoCalibrate), the function `cv2.stereoCalibrate()` should return 5 values when `flags=cv2.CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC`.

> Python: cv2.stereoCalibrate(objectPoints, imagePoints1, imagePoints2, cameraMatrix1, distCoeffs1, cameraMatrix2, distCoeffs2, imageSize[, R[, T[, E[, F[, flags[, criteria]]]]]]) → retval, cameraMatrix1, distCoeffs1, cameraMatrix2, distCoeffs2, R, T, E, F

and

> CV_CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC Fix cameraMatrix? and distCoeffs? so that only R, T, E , and F matrices are estimated.

**PS:** I found this [answer](http://answers.opencv.org/question/23392/camera-calibration-in-opencv-python-stereo-camera-errortoo-many-value-to-unpack/), but its not applicable for `cv2`.

Comment: can you assign returned values of `cv2.stereoCalibrate()` to a `list` and check number of values? that way you can confirm.

Comment: @Anil_M Thanks this worked. Looks like this is returning 9 values. But he documentation says something else.

Comment: `@harshatech2012` ,I  added my response as an answer , do you mind accepting it? That way the question wont hang as unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you assign returned values of `cv2.stereoCalibrate()` to a `list` and check number of values , you can come to know if it's indeed returning 5 values or something else. That way you can fix your receiving variables and tweak your code accordingly.